# Working of the distil networks bot detection

Tags: python, security, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape a website using Scrapy framework in python. But i am getting the captchas. The server implements the bot detection using Distil netwrok bot detection. Is there anyway i can work around with it?

Comment: I think you can't do much with it. Read [this](http://scraping.pro/distil-review-anti-scrape-bot-service/) for better acquaintance.

Comment: you might be interested how I've [tested](http://scraping.pro/distil-scrape-bot-protection-test/) it.

Comment: you can bypass it by using a headless browser, and you will need to remove all kind of global function or prototypes, fake the plugin array list, and more to do, then you will be able to bypass it easily.

Comment: See this answer if applicable: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56650941/11665017

Answer (score 0):

I personally drown it in proxies. 1 proxy for 4 requests before blocked, then I change proxy. I've several tens of thousands of free proxies, so it's not a big problem. But it's not very fast, so I set concurrency to 1k or about that.

Answer (score -8):

You can get over it by using tools like Selenium. It is a web testing framework that automatically loads the web browser to mimic a normal user. Once a page loads, you can scrape the content with tools such as Scrapy or Bs4. Continue loading the next page, then scrape. It's slower than normal scrapers but it does the job and gets through most detectors like Incapsula.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Terrible answer, Distil Networks was literally founded on the concept of stopping Selenium-based bots.

Comment: This won't work, Distil Networks can find and stop selenium and chrome-headless (which I have tried so far.